# Microsoft Bot Framework and Microsoft Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I need help with handle of Actions.Submit (button) in MS Teams..

If we pass "data": "message", we will get a standard dialog. If you test it in the emulator, everything works fine.

Thanks.

My AdaptiveCard:

```
    "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "p3",
      "data": {
        "text": "p3"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Помощь",
      "data": "p3"
    }
```

I need when clicking on any button to send a specific message

Comment: Did you add Invoke handler in your code? Please have a look at [this sample code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node/blob/1619b28e30cab50f1db7f39716df91fd64b7f32f/src/Bot.ts#L48).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is MS Teams bug. I report this.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, to make it work for Microsoft teams. Else for the emulator, you simply pass a string in Data.

```
dynamic dataObject = new JObject();
dataObject.msteams = new JObject();
dataObject.msteams.type = "imBack";
dataObject.msteams.value = intent.Value;
var actionSubmit = new AdaptiveSubmitAction(){
    Title = intent.Value,
    Data = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "emulator" ?  dataObject : intent.Value
};
```